# Root and meaning of the phrase 'couple two three'

Tags: slang, colloquialisms, vernacular

I'm not even sure where and how I picked up this phrase: 'couple two three'. It basically means 'a few' but I'm curious about its origins. It almost seems similar to 'might could' in that there is unnecessary redundancy.

Comment: I've never heard it either, but I note someone [here on slangvocabulary.com](http://www.slangvocabulary.com/wp/a/a-couple-two-three/) saying *We don’t say this in Chicago. It’s a weird thing they say **out west** or something.* That's the opposite side of the country to areas where the "Appalachian" dialect features redundancies such as "might could" (which imho, is indicative of more of limited linguistic ability in the speaker or his intended audience than of a "colourfully useful" dialect variation, but that's just my prejudiced opinion). Personally, I often say *a couple **or three***.

Comment: (My version is usually enunciated as ***a coupla-three***, obviously. Perhaps some people have simply misheard and/or misrepeated that relatively common colloquial construction.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers though note the comment on that slangvocabulary.com suggests more Midwest than far West, and my Kerouac quote may be East Coast

Comment: I am from the Midwest originally if that helps. Coupla-three is interesting because I may have picked up a variation.

Comment: Google Books claims about 93 written instances of [a couple or three beers](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22couple+or+three+beers%22), but there's just one instance of [couple two three beers](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22couple+or+three+beers%22#tbm=bks&q=%22couple+two+three+beers%22). And that one includes ***a comma after couple***, so it may just be another example of "hestitancy, on-the-fly quantification revision" as per that cited by @Henry, rather than [the idiomatic use being queried here.](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Coupletwothree)

Comment: Could it be a corruption/mis-remembering of _a couple **to** three_ (as a variant of _a couple or three_ or _two or three_)?

Answer (score 3):

A Google Books search for "couple two three" turns up only the instance that Henry cites in his answer. The source of that quotation is actually [*Pic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pic_(novel)) (1971), a novella by Kerouac that is told from the perspective of a character named Pictorial Review Jackson, a black child from North Carolina. Here is a [somewhat longer excerpt from the novella](https://books.google.com/books?id=kL00J4aSXcwC&pg=PT115&dq=%22couple+two+three+hunnerd%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjrsonJjefXAhVoqVQKHf1QDM8Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22couple%20two%20three%20hunnerd%22&f=false) containing the relevant passage, for context:

> **[Chapter] 12. Times Square and the Mystery of Television**
>
> There was a whole lot of men standin on the corner of Eighth Avenue and Forty Second in front of a big gray bank that was closed for the night. In the middle of the road it was all tore up from constructin work, and cars bumped by over the rocky sand along the sidewalk. It was a cold night for spring, felt more like autumn weather, and a whole lot of papers blowed by in the wind and the lights shined ever'whichside and flashed in that wind like so many eyes twinklin. It was jolly, and people had to be a wee bit frisky to keep warm, so they jumped about.  Me and Slim bought the hot dogs and spread some mustard on em, and strolled over to the corner to see what was goin on while they cooled a minute.
>
> Lord, there was **a couple two, three hunnerd** men on one side of the street. Most of them was listenin to the speeches of the Salvation Army. Four Salvations took turns makin speeches, and while one was speakin the other three jess stood there like ever'body else lookin up and down the street to see what else was goin on.

I checked several dictionaries of African-American slang, and none of them has an entry for anything remotely resembling "couple two three"—so the wording Kerouac uses may be his own invention or it may be an intentional or accidental mangling of "couple a three," which is (or was) a common idiomatic expression in parts of the United States, according to Harold Wentworth, *American Dialect Dictionary* (1944):

> **couple or three.** 2 or 3. **1930s e[astern W[est] V[irgini]a Berkeley Co[unty]** Freq[uent]. **1939 w[estern] W[est] V[irgini]a Huntington** Chiefly spoken. More rural than urban. Colloq[uial]. Almost invariably used. 'I saw him a couple a three weeks ago.'

There is currently no question on English Language & Usage on the origin of "a couple or three"/"a couple a three," but I hope to write up a question (and answer) on that topic in the near future.

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that this phrase was very common in and around Scranton, PA.  I don't recall seeing it in text, but growing up, I had always believed that it was "a couple *to* three." That would make more logical sense, as it would literally mean "2-3".

Answer (score 2):

I found more uses of "couple, two, three" or even "**couple-two-three**" in newspaper archives, mostly in quotations, suggesting the possibility of an idiomatic sense.

> "She's 80 years old," he said.  "I know nothing would happen to her.  I talk to my mother every **couple, two, three days**."

- **1974** - *Democrat and Chronicle* (Rochester, NY) 9 March 2B/1

> We get a **couple, two, three** (like complaints) a year," he said.

- **1995** - *The Post-Star* (Glens Falls, NY) 30 Sep. B9/3

The most convincing citations I found that suggest an idiomatic sense are these two clippings that hyphenate all the words together.

> You'll notice a lot between Frenchy's and the Palm Pavilion.  If it's full, there are a **couple-two-three** hidden lots that the locals know about.

- **2003** - *Tampa Bay Times* (St. Petersburg, FL) 2 March 85/3

> "That was my cue to make myself scarce for about half an hour.  Used to happen **couple-two-three** times a week."

- **1969** - *The Fresno Bee The Republican* (Fresno, CA) 28 Apr. 20/1

I have no conclusion as to the origins of the phrase, if it is indeed an idiomatic phrase.  Newspapers.com shows a large number of hits in Pennsylvania and New York, but that could be a result of the publications included in their corpus or misreadings of classified ads for couples seeking two or three rooms.

Answer (score 1):

This was originated in Scranton PA, and chiefly used very frequently in Northeast PA. Usually pronounced " a couple, two, tree" meaning a few in the valley slang speak of that area.

Comment: Do you have any sources to back this up so that it can be verified?

Comment: Someone posted that the origin for this phrase was Scranton, Pennsylvania. I was born and raised in PA. I've lived in western PA, I've lived in central PA, I've lived in southeast PA, and I've lived in northeast PA. The ONLY area in Pennsylvania where they use this phrase is the Scranton/Wilkes-Barre area in the northeast corner of the state (what we affectionately refer to as NEPA - pronounced nee-puh). So while I can't say that this is where the phrase originated, I can say that it somehow found its way to this part of Pennsylvania, and only this part of Pennsylvania.

Answer (score 1):

It's from I-talians...!   It can be either:  "couple-twos-threes" or, a: "couple-twos-t'rees."
I'm in Rochester, NY.   I-Talians are the plurality of denizens in Monroe County, especially in the inner suburb I grew up in and lived in for almost 30 years.    I suspect that younger people from my community don't use this 'term' as frequently (I'm 49).
It was definitely Italians, and even part Italians, who said this, but especially prevalent amongst those who had a parent who had immigrated to the US.     It was used as a somewhat ironic tipping-of-the-hat showing respect to the homeland.  And, also as a way to cement in-group status.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a clarification the use of *couple* to mean *a few* rather than *precisely two*.  So you might expect it more in spontaneous English than in something considered.

As an example, it appears near the start of chapter 12 of Jack Kerouac's *The Subterraneans*, set in New York:

> Lord, there was a couple two, three hunnerd men on one side of the street. Most of them were listenin to the speeches of the Salvation Army.

Comment: I don't think that cite reflects OP's usage. Kerouac could just as idiomatically have written *...there was/were **three, four, five hunnerd** of 'em.* That's just hesitating and being vague *while one thinks of a (maximum?) credible number*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think it is out of the question that 'couple two three' is the result of hesitation in the moment; it actually sounds like a plausible answer.

Comment: What an odd turn of phrase. I would have interpreted that Kerouac quote as saying there were between 400 and 600 men there.